# Kubernetes Helm Chart with different deployment.yaml

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I'm trying to define deployment.yaml , ingress.yaml and etc for Helm chart with dynamic values defined in values-dev.yaml, values-prod.yaml and etc.

So lets say that now I have two different deployment.yaml for two different env.

example deployment.yaml for dev

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-dev
  namespace: 'ctrl'
  labels:
    app: test-dev
spec:   #specification
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-dev
```

and example for deployment.yaml for local env

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-loc
  labels:
    app: test-loc
spec: #specification
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-loc
```

As you can see in the dev one there is an additional block if the type is RollingUpdate, that is missing in local yaml.

So my question is - in the new helm chart deployment.yaml can I define all the blocks that are currently existing in both depl-dev.yaml and depl-loc.yaml and just in the specific values-dev.yaml/values-loc.yaml NOT defining whats not required for specific env?

For example : deployment.yaml

```yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-dev
  namespace: 'ctrl'
  labels:
    app: test-dev
spec:   #specification
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: {{ .Values.type }}
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: {{ .Values.maxUnavailable }}
      maxSurge: {{ .Values.maxSurge }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-dev
```

With two values-dev.yaml / values-loc.yaml

```yaml
type: RollingUpdate.  | type: Recreate
maxUnavailable: 0
maxSurge: 1
```

Is this one going to work?

Answer (score 2):

[Helm doc](https://helm.sh/docs/chart_template_guide/function_list/#type-conversion-functions)

> toYaml: Convert list, slice, array, dict, or object to indented yaml, can be used to copy chunks of yaml from any source. This function is equivalent to GoLang yaml.Marshal function, see docs here: https://pkg.go.dev/gopkg.in/yaml.v2#Marshal

templates/deployment.yaml

```yaml
---
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: {{ .Values.test.name }}
  {{- if .Values.test.namespace }}
  namespace: {{ .Values.test.namespace | squote }}
  {{- end }}
  labels:
    app: {{ .Values.test.name }}
spec:
  replicas: {{ .Values.test.replicas }}
  strategy:
    {{- toYaml .Values.test.strategy | nindent 4 }}
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: {{ .Values.test.name }}
```

values-dev.yaml

```yaml
test:
  name: test-dev
  namespace: ctrl
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 0
      maxSurge: 1
```

output

```yaml
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-dev
  namespace: 'ctrl'
  labels:
    app: test-dev
spec:
  replicas: 2
  strategy:
    rollingUpdate:
      maxSurge: 1
      maxUnavailable: 0
    type: RollingUpdate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-dev
```

values-loc.yaml

```yaml
test:
  name: test-loc
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
```

output

```yaml
---
# Source: test/templates/deployment.yaml
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: test-loc
  labels:
    app: test-loc
spec:
  replicas: 1
  strategy:
    type: Recreate
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: test-loc
```

Answer (score 1):

Since `RollingUpdate` includes other attributes (`maxUnavailable`, `maxSurge`) compared with `Recreate` you should add a statement where you enter only if you specify RollingUpdates that will add those arguments:

```
strategy:
    type: {{ .Values.type }}
    {{- if eq .Values.type "RollingUpdate" }}
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: {{ .Values.maxUnavailable }}
      maxSurge: {{ .Values.maxSurge }}
    {{ end }}
```

with inside `values.yaml`:

```
type: RollingUpdate (or Recreate)
maxUnavailable: 0
maxSurge: 1
```